# Firebase and Azure Scheduled notifications in Xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am currently working on a xamarin.forms app that uses FireBase and Azure Notification Hub to send notifications to users. Using MessagingCenter I am passing the data between xamarin.android and xamarin.forms, as well as between xamarin.ios and xamarin.forms. My app allows users to put in reminders for when to take their medicines.

My question is, is there a way to activate notifications at a specified time? I know I should use some type of task or service for backgrounding but I can't find how to do this. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the notification to the NotificationHub, you can schedule it to fire in the future, as described in [this Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-send-push-notifications-scheduled):

```
Notification notification = new AppleNotification("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Happy birthday!\"}}");
var scheduled = await hub.ScheduleNotificationAsync(notification, new DateTime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0));
```

If you are sending notifications via a server, the server SDK you're using should have an equivalent method.